# std::stringstream: seeking advice

Tags: c++14, stringstream

The following is a piece of test code that I wrote to verify my understanding of how stringstream works:

```
#include<iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <algorithm>

using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using std::vector;
using std::string;
using std::stringstream;
using std::for_each;

int main (void){

   string s1 = "5";
   string s2 = "1 4 -1 6 0";
   vector<int> v;
   int val = 0;

   stringstream ss(s1);
   ss >> val;
   cout << "val: " << val << endl;

   ss.str(s2);
   while(val > 0){
      ss >> val;
      cout << "val: " << val << endl;
      v.push_back(val);
   }
   for_each(v.begin(), v.end(), [](int& i){cout << i << endl;});

   return 0;
}
```

When the code is compiled:

> g++ -ggdb -std=c++14 -Wall `<filename.cpp>`

and run, the value of `s1` is extracted and input into `val`.

In the second instance, trying to successively extract from `s2` and input into `val` doesn't work. `val` retains the value input into it from `s1` and hence the loop runs infinitely. The test condition of the loop, i.e., `val > 0`, is based on the following:

> If extraction fails, zero is written to value and failbit is set.

Reference: [std::basic_istream::operator>>](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/operator_gtgt)

What am I missing here?

TIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What am I missing here?

Add `ss.clear();` before the line `ss.str(s2);` to clear the error flags here EOF set by `ss >> val;`

After the execution will produce :

```
val: 5
val: 1
val: 4
val: -1
1
4
-1
```

Comment: @user9196120 yes you are right, I edited my answer. When you do  `ss >> val;` the stream reach the end of buffer, doing str(xx) doesn't affect the flags, clear() does